# Remove core and contrib. modules css files

Tags: 7

I would like to prevent several contributed modules from using their own css files. Constantly having to reset their css and then apply your own is a waste of bandwidth IMO.

I tried this out with nice_menus and it didn't seem to do anything.

Placed in template.php

```
    function phptemplate_variables($hook, $vars) {
        $css = drupal_add_css();

        $rm[] = drupal_get_path('module','nice_menus').'/nice_menus.css';
        $rm[] = drupal_get_path('module','nice_menus').'/nice_menus_default.css';

        foreach ($rm as $key => $value) {
            unset($css['all']['module'][$value]);
        }

        $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
    }
```

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: v6 (minimum 15 char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function should be named MYTHEME_preprocess_page.  Though a more common method is to add

```
stylesheets[all][] = nice_menus.css
```

to your theme's .info file.  nice_menus.css will be replaced by the one provided by your theme, or suppressed entirely if your theme doesn't contain this file.

Comment: Great thanks for your help. Both solutions worked.

Comment: Although, the preprocess seems to remove the IE-only files completely.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, use the following code.

```
function ko_css_alter(&$css) {
  if (isset($css['sites/all/modules/contrib/module/file.css'])) { 
    unset($css['sites/all/modules/contrib/module/file.css']);
  }
}
```

Comment: In D6 if you have the [advagg module](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) installed you can use hook_advagg_css_pre_alter to accomplish the same thing.